# Zeppelin - pass variable from Spark to Markdown to generate dynamic narrative text

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to pass a variable from Spark interpreter (pyspark or sql) to Markdown? The requirement is to display a nicely formatted text (i.e. Markdown) such as "20 events occurred between 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-08" where the 20, 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-08 are dynamically populated based on output from other paragraphs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting this for benefit of other users, this is what I have been able to find:

- Markdown paragraphs can only contain static text.
- But it is possible to achieve a dynamic formatted text output with the Angular interpreter instead.

(First paragraph)

```
%spark
// create data frame
val eventLogDF = ... 
// register temp table for SQL access
eventLogDF.registerTempTable( "eventlog" )

val query = sql( "select max(Date), min(Date), count(*) from eventlog" ).take(1)(0)
val maxDate = query(0).toString()
val minDate = query(1).toString()
val evCount = query(2).toString()

// bind variables which can be accessed from angular interpreter 
z.angularBind( "maxDate", maxDate )
z.angularBind( "minDate", minDate )
z.angularBind( "evCount", evCount )
```

(Second paragaph)

```
%angular

<div>There were <b>{{evCount}} events</b> between <b>{{minDate}}</b> and <b>{{maxDate}}</b>.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also print out markdown by translate it into HTML first, for those who may already have an markdown template for output, or your Zeppelin environment have no Angular interpreter(e.g. a K8s deployment).

First, install [markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2).

```
%sh
pip install markdown2
```

And use it.

```
%pyspark
import markdown2

# prepare your markdown string
markdown_string = template_mymarkdown.format(**locals())
# use Zeppelin %html for output
print("%html", markdown2.markdown(markdown_string, extras=["tables"]))
```

A screenshot for example:

[image: spark markdown2html]